Is there a unitary operator for this multi qubit addition?
Is there a quantum unitary operator $U$ that
takes   the tensor product of the two equiprobable states
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|a_1\rangle+|a_2\rangle\big)
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|b_1\rangle+|b_2\rangle\big)
$$
and gives
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|a_1+b_1\rangle+|a_2+b_2\rangle\big)
$$
as its output?
where the $a_i$ and $b_i$, or $i=1,2,...$ above are non-negative
integers less than $-1+2^n$ for some integer $n$.
In other words U simply does addition of $a_1+a_2$,
and puts the answer in  a ket, and does addition of $b_1+b_2$,
and puts the answer in   a ket
for example
$$
U\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|2\rangle+|5\rangle\big)\otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|4\rangle+|10\rangle\big)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\big(|6\rangle+|15\rangle\big)
$$
does there exist a quantum unitary operator $U$ for the obvious generalisation for some integer m for adding
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\big(|a_1\rangle+|a_2\rangle+...+|a_{m}\rangle\big)
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\big(|b_1\rangle+|b_2\rangle+...+|b_{m}\rangle\big)
$$
to give
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\big(|a_1+b_1\rangle+|a_2+b_2\rangle +...+|a_{m}+b_{m}\rangle\big)
$$
for some power of 2 for $m$?

I don't think there will be any linear operator doing this, since your map seems to depend on the order you write the superposition, making the map ill-defined.

You could do this if you had some index register and your states were superpositions of the form $|i\rangle|a_i\rangle$ and $|i\rangle|b_i\rangle$, producing $|i\rangle|a_i + b_i\rangle$.

Yes, but I think the superposition is the tricky part, no? One can prepare a superposition between $\lvert i \rangle \lvert a_i + b_i \rangle$ and $\lvert j \rangle \lvert a_j + b_j \rangle$, but once you trace out the ancillas you get only a classical mixture of the two states.

The operator the way you would like it, at least in my eyes cannot exist, this is firstly because it depends on the order you write the superposition (comment by Refik Mansuroglu). It is also not reversible, since the result could have had multiple inputs, e.g.
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\big(|6\rangle+|15\rangle\big) = U\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|2\rangle+|5\rangle\big)\otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|4\rangle+|10\rangle\big)= U\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|3\rangle+|5\rangle\big)\otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|3\rangle+|10\rangle\big)
$$
Multiple input states, cannot have the same output state and keep the reversiblity.
You are left with three options: keep some garbage ancillas, restrict your input states, perhaps adding a constraint such that $b \geq a$ could help, and or to add ancillary qubits.
If you are happy to keep a register (to use in-place) adder, you can add a $2 \cdot log_2(m)$ register to $a$ and $b$ (as suggested by xzkxyz), to track the index, you can then control a quantum-quantum adder, such as the TTK adder, depending on if the index is the same. Notice that you will need more qubits to do this, since the result (register b which we will override, needs more space to fully store the numbers, unless you store them mod $2^n$).
In the quantum world this would look like (as an example): a multi-controlled quantum-quantum adder (such as the TTK adder), where the controlled qubits are the index, you would then need one to filter out each possible index, which would be $2^m$ possibilities (every single subset of bits to $m$) Importantly, you would need to make sure you check the $0$s aswell, not only the $1$s. This would be an exponential algorithm, but its the closest I could get in a half hour of work; it would then do the following:
$$
U\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|1\rangle|2\rangle+|2\rangle|5\rangle\big)\otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|1\rangle|4\rangle+|2\rangle|10\rangle\big)
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|1\rangle|2\rangle+|2\rangle|5\rangle\big)\otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|1\rangle|6\rangle+|2\rangle|15\rangle\big)
$$
Notice that in the resulting state, you keep your states $|1\rangle|2\rangle+|2\rangle|5\rangle$ or else it wouldn't be reversible. In principle, one could consider these garbage ancillas if you don't need them, but you also cannot measure them or reset them without collapsing the superposition.
I am nearly sure you could improve this operator, I don't feel like it has to be exponential, there may be nicer schemes to make this work.

I am relatively new to the QCSE, some answers might not be completely accurate, feel free to correct me, please do so in a constructive manner :).
